# converting a proper xml to improper xml

Tags: java, xml

I have a requirement and I need to convert the given proper xml to a improper format using java.

Xml which I receive is something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<start>
   <level>5</level>
   <mode>passive</mode>
   <directory>home/lib/dir</directory>
   <reach_port>8888</reach_port>
   <languages default="en">en,ar,bn</languages>
   <Server_port>8800</Server_port>
   <reset_time>180</reset_time>
   <refresh_rate>10</refresh_rate>
</start>
```

I need to convert it into below format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<1start>                 -> XML Tag is starting with number 
   <level>5</level>
   <mode>passive</mode>
   <directory>home/lib/dir</directory>
   <reach_port="8888"/>  -> Syntax is not recognizable
   <languages default="en">en,ar,bn</languages>
   <Server_port="8800"/> -> Syntax is not recognizable
   <reset_time="180"/>   -> Syntax is not recognizable
   <refresh_rate="10"/>  -> Syntax is not recognizable
</1start>
```

I need to strictly stick to this format as the further dependency requires the xml in this format. 
I dont know how to proceed as I cant think of any standard approach towards it, Any suggestion on the best way to handle.

Comment: the best way would be to have the xml be made up in the right format the first time

Comment: sadly that is not an option as the xml is created by the ui, and it only supports proper formats

Comment: I think you need to do a manual encoding, since the latter format is not `xml`. I could understand something like `<reach port="8888" />` without the `_`

Comment: So, a dependency created its very own proprietary document format which vaguely resembles XML. Doesn't it provide a parser/generator that supports this proprietary format? Isn't such crap a good indication that you should not depend on that dependency?

Comment: how to do this as manual encoding? if the xml expands manual encoding is a trouble. isn't it?

Comment: I think the more pressing matter is "why do you do it"? Why would you even want 'improper xml' ?

Comment: An application has been developed which expects xml in this format, cannot revert back the application as it is out of my reach to do it.

Comment: I need to get my xml in this format, any approach is welcomed

Comment: @MohammedAaqib XSLT can help you to automatize the transformation: XML -> custom format

Comment: The downstream application is bound to get fixed for all sorts of other reasons. I wouldn't waste any time on building co-operating bugs to make it look as though it works. It doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no good answers to this question, but here's a way to do it with Java

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XmlInvalidGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException, JDOMException {
        final String xmlString = ""
                + "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>"
                + "<start>"
                + "<level>5</level>"
                + "<mode>passive</mode>"
                + "<directory>home/lib/dir</directory>"
                + "<reach_port>8888</reach_port>"
                + "<languages default=\"en\">en,ar,bn</languages>"
                + "<Server_port>8800</Server_port>"
                + "<reset_time>180</reset_time>"
                + "<refresh_rate>10</refresh_rate>"
                + "</start>";

        final Document document = new SAXBuilder().build(new StringReader(xmlString));

        final Element start = document.getRootElement();

        final String level = start.getChild("level").getValue();
        final String mode = start.getChild("mode").getValue();
        final String directory = start.getChild("directory").getValue();
        final String reach_port = start.getChild("reach_port").getValue();
        final Element languages = start.getChild("languages");
        final String server_port = start.getChild("Server_port").getValue();
        final String reset_time = start.getChild("reset_time").getValue();
        final String refresh_rate = start.getChild("refresh_rate").getValue();

        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>");
        stringBuilder.append("<1start?").append("\n");
        stringBuilder.append("<level>").append(level).append("</level>").append("\n");
        stringBuilder.append("<mode>").append(mode).append("</mode>").append("\n");
        stringBuilder.append("<directory>").append(directory).append("</directory>").append("\n");
        stringBuilder.append("<reach_port=\"").append(reach_port).append("\"/>").append("\n");
        stringBuilder.append("<languages default=\"").append(languages.getAttribute("default").getValue()).append("\">").append(languages.getValue()).append("</languages").append("\n");
        stringBuilder.append("<Server_port=\"").append(server_port).append("\"/>").append("\n");
        stringBuilder.append("<reset_time=\"").append(reset_time).append("\"/>").append("\n");
        stringBuilder.append("<refresh_rate=\"").append(refresh_rate).append("\"/>").append("\n");

        stringBuilder.append("</1start>");

        System.out.println("stringBuilder = " + stringBuilder);
    }

    private static void printStartElement(Element start) {
        System.out.println("start.getChildren().size() = " + start.getChildren().size());
        System.out.println("level = " + start.getChild("level").getValue());
        System.out.println("mode = " + start.getChild("mode").getValue());
        System.out.println("directory = " + start.getChild("directory").getValue());
        System.out.println("reach_port = " + start.getChild("reach_port").getValue());
        final Element languages = start.getChild("languages");
        System.out.println("languages(default=" + languages.getAttribute("default").getValue() + "): " + languages.getValue());
        System.out.println("Server_port = " + start.getChild("Server_port").getValue());
        System.out.println("reset_time = " + start.getChild("reset_time").getValue());
        System.out.println("refresh_rate = " + start.getChild("refresh_rate").getValue());
    }
}
```

Good luck

Comment: It Works! Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. It was kind of fun. I hadn't used JDOM in a while. It's a nice API, but I still prefer groovy :-P

Answer (score 4):

Blech! Welcome to real-world software engineering :(. If I understand the question correctly, your only requirement is to *generate* this crap, and not *parse* it. Count your blessings! JB Nizet is absolutely correct that you shouldn't have to be made to do this, but sometimes you're left no choice. If I got a dime for every time I had to similarly compensate for an external party's incompetence…

Architecture wise, the key thing is (obviously) to put a Crap Isolation Layer at the very edge of your system, i.e. process everything in a sane manner within your system bounds and leave this tag soup format for the very last stage of output. From the looks of it, you're already doing that.

An XSLT template such as this would work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/start">
        <xsl:text>&lt;1start&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text>&lt;/1start&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/start/level">
        <xsl:text>&lt;level&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        <xsl:text>&lt;/level&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/start/reach_port">
        <xsl:text>&lt;reach_port=&quot;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        <xsl:text>&quot;/&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- process other elements in the same way -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I dont know much about  XSLT but surely will look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use SAX, see [Simple API for XML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/index.html), receive each element in turn and write the converted element to a text stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
\<([^_<>]*_[^_<>]*)\>([^<>]*)\<[^_<>]*_[^_<>]*\>
```

Replace all with

```
<$1="$2"/>
```

That will make this ----> into this

```
<reach_port>8888</reach_port> ----> <reach_port="8888"/>
```